# Can we connect to SQL Server 2005 database from code with out having the installation of client and server

Tags: java, sql-server-2005

I need to retrieve data from the database. I have the database name, username, password, servername, but I don't have the software installed in my machine. Can I connect to the db and retrieve the data from the db from database from Java code?

Comment: <dws>To do it without a driver, try using magic.</dws>  Also please note that imploring people to realize "it is very urgent" is likely to bring you less replies, later, rather than more, sooner.  DWS - dripping with sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have database drivers atleast like ODBC or JDBC drivers on your system where application runs to access the DB from other machine.

Answer (score 0):

From Java, it's easy as long as there is some kind of driver installed (for example, ODBC.) Try Googling [connecting to db using odbc](https://www.google.com/search?q=connecting+to+db+using+odbc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The jdbc driver .jar can be used stand alone. It logs a warning about a missing .dll, but that can be ignored unless you need to use windows auth.